# Wordpress + plugin Magic Members (custom field checkbox doesn't work)

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Have some issue with registration page at client's site. In case to register user need to accept terms by clicking on a several checkboxes (https://prnt.sc/-5J17cPrWj6c screenshot)

But when after that I'm checking that user in Users at admin panel I see that some of those checkboxes are empty. Especially the last one. (https://prnt.sc/1Du99fKV4gqS screenshot). And even if I click that checkbox and update user manually it still remains empty after update.

That checkbox I added with Magic Members plugin. (https://prnt.sc/x9gTYmM7xkhP screenshot).

Any tips what can it be and what should I do?